# How to deal with invisible mites?

Tags: pest-control, insect

I do not feel them, but the two females in the house complain of being bitten by the largely invisible mites. The bites itch and the overall situation disgusts them...

The pests are, probably, [bird mites](http://www.birdmites.org/), though we aren't entirely sure. If they are, indeed, mites, then the products meant against *flying* insects may not work...

What sort of thing would you recommend to kill the suckers -- without injuring the human (and canine) residents of the same residence?

Comment: Based on the information in your link, it sounds like an exterminator might be the best option.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure, without knowing exactly what you're dealing with. Bring in an exterminator, they should be able to determine the pest.

Comment: invisible bug spray?

Comment: Could be bed bugs. You never see them because they come out when it is dark. What do the bite marks look like? Are there several bites in a row, like a line of small red bites?

Comment: This almost sounds like the medical condition, scabies? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scabies

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug question, probably better suited for Outdoors or Gardening, and it's been abandoned for years.

Answer (score 1):

It could be mites from another type of animal, such as mice. I get bites in the garden in the summer from invisible mites. I don't know how to get rid of them but next summer I was going to try putting vaseline or olive oil on my legs. The olive oil works for no-see-ems in Mexico, as they drown in it.